# ¿Cómo obtener los registros de una tabla siempre y cuando no este repetido en otra tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

estoy haciendo una base de datos para registrar tareas de alumnos, tengo 2 tablas que están unidas
una se llama 'tarea' (donde se registran todas las tareas que hay en una clase) y la otra tabla se llama tareas entregadas (guarda la tarea subida del alumno) y lo que necesito es mostrarle a los alumnos las tareas que no estén en la segunda tabla (que no han sido entregadas)

esta es la tabla tareas entregadas

cod_tarea es foranea y esta relacionada con la tabla tareas,
y clave es otra foranea que estar relacionada con el alumno
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la tabla de tareas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo obtener las tareas que el alumno no ha subido?

Comment: Si esa relacion es 1 a 1... porque no estan en la misma tabla? o es por algun tipo de optimizacion?

Comment: igual, intentaste algo? porque se resuelve con un not in....

Comment: @gbianchi es que hay n numero de alumnos que pueden subir su trabajo a una tarea de clase y cada trabajo del alumno tiene una calificación

Comment: y como sabes que alumno entrego que tarea? el alumno no esta en la tarea entregada.. o no esta la tabla completa mostrada?

Comment: @gbianchi haa ok es que clave en la tabla de tareas entregadas es el alumno que ha entregado esa tarea y los alumnos que están registrados en una clase están guardados en otra tabla

Comment: Bueno, eso no esta claro ni en la pregunta, ni en ningun lado. Te recomendaria que intentaras resolver algo, y luego de ello expliquen claramente como se conectan las tablas (ya que tampoco esta claro) y de donde quieres sacar cada dato. Agregar lo que intentaste y donde fallo es un paso principal para obtener una respuesta